# Adding Text to Text if Condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

How can I in jQuery or plain Javascript add text if condition is met?

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">                
<label for="foo">Foo Text</label>                
<input type="checkbox" id="bar">                
<label for="bar">Bar Text</label>            
<p class="success" style="display: none;">Thank you for </p>        
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success pull-left">SUBSCRIBE</button>
```

Not I need a logic that will place a "Bar Text" or "Foot Text" depending which checkbox is checked, after the submit is clicked.

I know I have to use `.is(:checked)` but I do not know how to place a text dynamically after the static "Thank you " text.

Also, I would like a jQuery and Javascript solution, if possible, for learning purposes only.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, show us what you tried already

Comment: I did.. that is all unfortunatelly

Comment: And where should the '*"Bar Text" or "Foot Text"*' be placed?

Comment: after the "thank you "

Comment: Okay, and where did you get stuck when you attempted to write this yourself? What part, or parts, don't you understand or struggle with?

Comment: I want foo text or bar text to be added depending on which checkbox was checked, after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: We know what you want; what I am asking is "*where did you get stuck? Why haven't you written more than the HTML?*" Also, given that you're using check-boxes (in which both, or neither, can be checked) what should happen if they're both checked? What should happen if neither is checked?

Comment: What should happend i both checkboxes checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch the text you need this :

```
$("#data").find("input:checked").next("label").text();
     ^                ^                 ^        ^----------|
Where to look    What to find     Where to navigate    What to get
```

> So basically, search in #data div for checked checkboxes and grab the
>   text of the label next to them.

Read :

1. https://api.jquery.com/find/
2. https://api.jquery.com/next/
3. https://api.jquery.com/text/

```js
$(function() {
  var prevText = $(".success").text();
  $("#submit-form").click(function() {
    var text = $("#data").find("input:checked").next("label").text();
    $(".success").text(prevText + " " + text).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo">
  <label for="foo"> Foo Text</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar">
  <label for="bar"> Bar Text</label>
</div>
<p class="success" style="display: none;">Thank you for</p>
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success pull-left">SUBSCRIBE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$("#submit-form").on("click",function(){
  $(".success:eq(0)").text("Thank you for");
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(".success:eq(0)").show().append(" " +        $(this).next("label").text());
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">                
<label for="foo">Foo Text</label>                
<input type="checkbox" id="bar">                
<label for="bar">Bar Text</label>            
<p class="success" style="display: none;">Thank you for </p>        
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success pull-left">SUBSCRIBE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `map()` to return array with text of label that is `next` of input that is checked and use `join()` to transform that array to text.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  var text = $('input').map(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) return $(this).next('label').text()
  }).get().join(', ');

  (text != '') ? $('p.success').text('Thank you for ' + text).show(): $('p.success').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<label for="foo">Foo Text</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="bar">
<label for="bar">Bar Text</label>
<p class="success" style="display: none;">Thank you for</p>
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success pull-left">SUBSCRIBE</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is an jQuery example to get started.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var text = $(this).next('label').text();
    $('.success').text("Thank you for " + text).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<label for="foo">Foo Text</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="bar">
<label for="bar">Bar Text</label>
<p class="success" style="display: none;"></p>
<br/>
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success pull-left">SUBSCRIBE</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
 <input type="checkbox" id="foo" class="chkBox">                
 <label for="foo">Foo Text</label>                
 <input type="checkbox" id="bar" class="chkBox">                
 <label for="bar">Bar Text</label>
</div>
<p class="success" style="display: none;">Thank you for </p>        
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success pull-left">SUBSCRIBE</button>
```

jQuery

```
var checked = $('div.container').find('input:checked').attr("id");
var textNeeded = $("[for=" + checked + "]").text();
$('.success').text("Thank you for " + textNeeded).show();
```